# Pointer tho another Object

Tags: c++

I  have a little problem ..  I want to do car registration and i want to have owner(pointer to a Person object) but when i want to take the owner with get function i can't do that ... and this is mystery for me ... Maybe i have a little mistake somewhere and i can't find it .. Please help :)

```
class Person
{
    friend class Cars;
public:
    Person(){}
    Person(uint8_t age, string name) :m_age(age), m_name(name)
    {
        m_idGener = s_idGenerator++;
    }

    int getId()
    {
        return m_idGener;
     }
    uint8_t getAge()
    {
        return m_age;
    }
    string getName()
    {
     return m_name;
    }
 private:
    string m_name;
    uint8_t m_age;
    static int s_idGenerator;
    int m_idGener;

 };
 class Cars:public Person
 {

 public:
     Person *m_owner; // this is my pointer which i want to point to cars     Object 
  it will stay public for the test after the test i will move it in the     private section 
    Cars()
    {
    }
   // getters and setters 

    Cars setOwner(Cars &object, Person &owner) // with this function i set the owner 
    {
      object.m_owner = &owner;
    }
    Cars getOwner(Cars &object) /// here is my problem i can't take the owner 
    {
       return *(object.m_owner); // but i can't take the owner 
    }

     uint16_t getHorsePower()
    {
       return horsePower;
    }
     string getRegNumber()
    {
       return registrationNumber;
    }
  private:
     string m_manufacturerName;
     string modelName;
     uint16_t horsePower;
    string registrationNumber;

};

int Person::s_idGenerator = 0;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made more mistakes. At least the followings should be corrected:

```
Cars setOwner(Cars &object,  .....
```

This method doest not return a value, so it should be void. The car object should be the object for which the method will be called, not a parameter.

```
Cars getOwner(Cars &object) /// here is my problem i can't take the owner 
{
   return *(object.m_owner); // but i can't take the owner 
}
```

In this method I would change the return type to `Person *`, then return simply `m_owner`. Parameter is not needed.

A modified working example:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Person
{
    friend class Cars;
public:
    Person(){}
    Person(uint8_t age, string name) :m_age(age), m_name(name)
    {
        m_idGener = s_idGenerator++;
    }

    int getId()
    {
        return m_idGener;
     }
    uint8_t getAge()
    {
        return m_age;
    }
    string getName()
    {
     return m_name;
    }
 private:
    string m_name;
    uint8_t m_age;
    static int s_idGenerator;
    int m_idGener;

 };
 class Cars:public Person
 {

 public:
     Person *m_owner; // this is my pointer which i want to point to cars     Object 
                      // it will stay public for the test after the test i will move it in the     private section 
    Cars()
    {
    }
   // getters and setters 

    void setOwner(Person &owner) // with this function i set the owner 
    {
      m_owner = &owner;
    }
    Person *getOwner() /// here is my problem i can't take the owner 
    {
       return (m_owner); // but i can't take the owner 
    }

     uint16_t getHorsePower()
    {
       return horsePower;
    }
     string getRegNumber()
    {
       return registrationNumber;
    }
  private:
     string m_manufacturerName;
     string modelName;
     uint16_t horsePower;
    string registrationNumber;

};

int Person::s_idGenerator = 0;

int main() {
  Person p(5,"Bill");
  Cars c;

  c.setOwner(p);
  cout << c.getOwner()->getName();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much i am beginner and now i am learning to code :)

Comment: You are welcome. If it was helpful for you, you may consider to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
Cars setOwner(Cars &object, Person &owner) // with this function i set the owner
{ 
object.m_owner = &owner;
}
```

You declared out value type as "Cars" but you don't return anything.

And here:

```
Cars getOwner(Cars &object) /// here is my problem i can't take the owner
{ 
return *(object.m_owner); // but i can't take the owner 
}
```

You want to return "Person" object but again you declared out value type as "Cars".

So you can change this functions like that:

First:

```
void setOwner(Cars &object, Person &owner);
```

Second:

```
Person getOwner(Cars &object);
```